# How do I save multiple checkbox values in a single column separately in the database and retrieve it using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I want to store all the selected check box values in single-column separately like
[image]

here is my code for that

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Posts" readonly>
    </th>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Add">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="View">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Edit">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Comments" readonly>
    </th>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Add">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="View">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Edit">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="User" readonly>
    </th>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Add">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="View">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Edit">
    </td>
    <td class="examplelink">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
```

And want to store individually with its supporting read-only text? how to do that ???
And when user checks the checkbox (selected) should be stored in the database??
how to write store function for it ???

here is my ui of form :
[image]

Comment: Why do all your checkboxes have the same name (`checkPermission[]`) instead of suffixing them with their permission (`checkPermission_add[]`, `checkPermission_view[]`, etc.)?

Comment: because want to make them array first and save them individually in database. let me update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store all checkbox values using the markup you showed, you won't be able to know which permission belongs to which model.

If you have to use that exact name and can't provide more then one key => value as post data (for some reason), you would have to add some more info to the value field.

**Example:**

```
  <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Comments" readonly>
        </th>
        <td class="examplelink">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="comment_Add">
        </td>
        <td class="examplelink">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="comment_View">
        </td>
        <td class="examplelink">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="comment_Edit">
        </td>
        <td class="examplelink">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="comment_Delete">
        </td>
  </tr>
```

Then when retrieving the data in back-end you would have to explode each value using delimiter "_" to find model at index 0 and permission at index 1.

**EDIT: Or you could build a JS object containing all the data and send it as JSON data.**

Comment: thanks man, I have done like this and I am getting an array of that..

Comment: but could you help how to get all the selected array check box to edit page , can't able to figure out ..

Comment: first you have to prepare the data in your controller, and when returning the view you can use `return view('blade_file')->with(compact('someVariable'));` so that you can access the data from the view. Then in your blade file you can do something like this: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkPermission[]" value="comment_Add"{{ ($someVariable['comment_Add'] === true ? ' checked' : '') }}>`

Comment: thanks brother , but could you help how to save it in store method @Andrew Larsen

Comment: i don't have to save in json object , but as shown in first image of question

Comment: @hapuu example (https://pastebin.com/bi0epibC), code is not tested.