# how to retrieve array of old selected checkbox to edit blade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, controller

I am facing an error , I want to fetch the array of selected checked box , which are saved in the database like this - [image]

, and the view of this is like : [image]

now the thing is that , I have used role_id as  a id to access it , means when user click on edit button associated with id = 1 means admin , the permissions set with role_id 1 should be fetched on the edit page . the ui of edit page is like this :
[image]

,now how to retrieve all the selected checkbox back to the edit option and means all the permission, either it is post , comment , user etc.
how to show them on blade?

here are the controller of edit :

```
  public function edit($role_id,Request $request)
    {
       
        $role_data = RolePermission::where(['role_id' => $role_id])->get();
      
        
        return view('AssignPermission.edit',compact('role_data'));
    }
```

and here is the view of blade file??

```
    <td class="examplelink">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="Permissions[]" value="PostAdd"  @if (is_array(old('Permissions')) && in_array('PostAdd', old('Permissions'))) {{"checked='checked'"}}@endif>
                    </td>
```

how to retrieve all the data to the edit form???

edit :  here is the result of dd($role_data->toArray())
[image]

I am storing value as static like this:

```
        public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
       'Roles' => 'required',
    );

    $validate=Validator::make($data,$rules);
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validate);
    }
    else{
       
         $data = $request->all();
        //  dd($data);   

        // Post CheckBox

        if(in_array('PostAdd', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $PostAdd = new RolePermission;
            $PostAdd->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $PostAdd->Item = 'Post';
            $PostAdd->Permission = 'Add';
            $PostAdd->save();
        }
        if(in_array('PostView', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $PostView = new RolePermission;
            $PostView->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $PostView->Item = 'Post';
            $PostView->Permission = 'View';
            $PostView->save();
        }
        
        if(in_array('PostEdit', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $PostEdit = new RolePermission;
            $PostEdit->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $PostEdit->Item = 'Post';
            $PostEdit->Permission = 'Edit';
            $PostEdit->save();
        }

        if(in_array('PostDelete', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $PostDelete = new RolePermission;
            $PostDelete->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $PostDelete->Item = 'Post';
            $PostDelete->Permission = 'Delete';
            $PostDelete->save();
        }

        // Comment checkBox
        if(in_array('CommentAdd', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $CommentAdd = new RolePermission;
            $CommentAdd->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $CommentAdd->Item = 'Comment';
            $CommentAdd->Permission = 'Add';
            $CommentAdd->save();
        }
        if(in_array('CommentView', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $CommentView = new RolePermission;
            $CommentView->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $CommentView->Item = 'Comment';
            $CommentView->Permission = 'View';
            $CommentView->save();
        }
        if(in_array('CommentEdit', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $CommentEdit = new RolePermission;
            $CommentEdit->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $CommentEdit->Item = 'Commment';
            $CommentEdit->Permission = 'Edit';
            $CommentEdit->save();
        }
        if(in_array('CommentDelete', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $CommentDelete = new RolePermission;
            $CommentDelete->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $CommentDelete->Item = 'Comment';
            $CommentDelete->Permission = 'Delete';
            $CommentDelete->save();
        }


        // User CheckBox
        if(in_array('UserAdd', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $UserAdd = new RolePermission;
            $UserAdd->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $UserAdd->Item = 'User';
            $UserAdd->Permission = 'Add';
            $UserAdd->save();
        }
        if(in_array('UserView', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $UserView = new RolePermission;
            $UserView->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $UserView->Item = 'User';
            $UserView->Permission = 'View';
            $UserView->save();
        }
        if(in_array('UserEdit', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $UserEdit = new RolePermission;
            $UserEdit->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $UserEdit->Item = 'User';
            $UserEdit->Permission = 'Edit';
            $UserEdit->save();
        }
        if(in_array('UserDelete', $request->get('Permissions'))){
            $UserDelete = new RolePermission;
            $UserDelete->role_id = $request->Roles;
            $UserDelete->Item = 'User';
            $UserDelete->Permission = 'Delete';
            $UserDelete->save();
        }
            
            $Message = "successfully added";
            return redirect('/Admin/AssignPermission')->with('success',$Message);
        }   
    }
```

do let me know ?? if this method is right or not ?? suggest other meethodt to store and retrieve data ???

updated code:
here is the function of edit :

```
    public function edit($role_id,Request $request)
    {
       
        $role_data = RolePermission::where(['role_id' => $role_id])->get()->map(function ($role){

            return $role->Item.$role->Permission;
        });;
        
        return view('AssignPermission.edit',compact('role_data'));
    }
```

and here is the updated code of blade:

```
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Permissions[]" value="PostAdd" {{is_array(old('Permissions',$role_data??[])) && in_array('PostAdd',old('Permissions',$role_data??[]))?'checked':null}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="Permissions[]" value="PostAdd" {{is_array(old('Permissions',$role_data??[]))&&in_array('PostAdd',old('Permissions',$role_data??[]))?'checked':null}} />
```

In controller

```
   $role_data = RolePermission::where(['role_id' => $role_id])->get()->map(function ($role){

        return $role->Item.$role->Permission;
    })->toArray();
```

Comment: thanks brother , but still empty in edit option

Comment: is it role_data you want to populate to checkbox ?

Comment: sorry noob here, thought would fetching from permissions can solve error , but yes u are right brother , I have to fetch from role_data , should I share my store method also , where you can get idea of it

Comment: can you show dd($role_data->toArray()) data if you want to populate to $role_data

Comment: I have updated question, kindly look at it

Comment: @hapuu where is the value PostAdd in database table ?

Comment: hey there, I am using this as value but storing like static in it ...should I update my question to show how I am inserting data into database

Comment: check the updated question... is it right method to store like this or use @foreach method  , but with that method, was getting so much error and , was not able to store the data..

Comment: here is the link of that question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68254457/16114539

Comment: dude.. changed but same error, not showing selected checked box

Comment: can you show screenshot of upated code of blade and controller

Comment: @you should append data and then pass second argument to old

Comment: hey there.. getting an error , the selected  data is not been shown on edit blade .. @John Lobo

Comment: @hapuu  test line by line see where it causing error

Comment: error solved , my typo mistake... ..thanks once again